# When solving elliptic PDE by finding the critical point of its engergy functional, is there 'local maximizer'?

Tags: functional-analysis

When solving elliptic PDE by finding the critical point of its engergy functional, why we always want the 'minimizer' instead of 'maximizer'?

For the global minimizer and maximizer, of course as long as it's coercivity, then there is no global maximizer, but what about local maximizer, is there possibility that a solution is the local maximizer of the energy functional?

Comment: If the energy is not convex, then critical points can be local maximizers of the energy.